# jquery accessing parameters between html pages without server side interaction and window.location

Tags: jquery, url, parameter-passing

I have an html page which is made of 2 divs ( left panel and right panel ). left div is loaded with values from backend. On selection of a value on the left div, i want to load a html page on the right div and want to pass a parameter with the url of page being loaded. I am using jquery for loading the right div with the html page and i am passing the parameter too in the url ( like ("#.editor").load("editor.html?method="+m) ).

Now My question is how do i access the value 'method' in the other html page. I tried using window.location.href to access the value with no avail. Kindly help. I have pasted the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link type="text/css" href="./methodeditor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="../../css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
<title>Method editor</title>
<script>
function gethtml(m){
    $(".editor").load('editor.html?method='+m );


}
function save(){
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
    var win = editor.contentWindow;
    var form = win.document.getElementById("editor");
    form.submit();
}

function getmethods() {


    $.get ("listmethods.php" , function(data) {  
    var methods = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i=0; i< methods.length; i++){
    $(".list").append("<div id=" + methods[i] + " class= clickable ><tr><td>" + methods[i] + "</td></tr></div>");
    }
    });


}

$('.clickable').live('click', function() {
        var m = this.id;
        gethtml(m);

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="methodeditor">
<div class="list">
<script>
getmethods();
</script>
</div>
<div class="editor" >
<script>
gethtml('default.xml');
</script>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()"  />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a higher scoped (perhaps global) variable and set it with the method's name in (m). Using an object orientated approach on this one might ease things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/2880929#2880929). How to get the parameters passed in the query string with JavaScript.